# How to fix 'The requested address is not valid in its context' for local ip

Tags: python, python-3.x, opensoundcontrol

I'm attempting to add an Open Sound Control (UDP) listener to a python program, but I keep getting the error "OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context". The program works when accessing my own ip, but not when I attempt to add a listener to a different ip. I know I cannot acces external ip's but the computer I am trying to access is on the same network.

I have tried different OSC listeners (pyOSC, python-osc) but they don't work. However, a OSC program I have installed (OSCwidgets) is able to access the other computer, so I know it is just the python program that does not work.

Here is the file I am working with (not including the error handlers):

```py
from OSC import OSCServer, OSCClient, OSCMessage
import types

server = OSCServer(("192.168.86.34", 8000))

def test_callback(path, tags, args, source):
    if path=="/test":
        print("pyOSC Receive: " + str(path) + " = " + args[0])

server.addMsgHandler("/test",test_callback)

while True:
    server.handle_request()
```

The program should simply print the OSC packet received from the specified ip. The full error that occurs is below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/red4d/Documents/GitHub/ETC-Eos-OSC-Controller/pyOSCreceivetest.py", line 5, in <module>
    server = OSCServer(("192.168.86.34", 8000))
  File "C:\Users\red4d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\OSC.py", line 1716, in __init__
    UDPServer.__init__(self, server_address, self.RequestHandlerClass)
  File "C:\Users\red4d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "C:\Users\red4d\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you included a link to the pipy page for the OSC API that you're using.